`RequestDeviceError { inner: Core(DeviceLost) }` when using wgpu on an intel integrated gpu
I a trying to use wgpu to run a compute shader for a rust project, however I can not get adapter.request_device to not fail. I have copied the hello compute example directly from wgpu's repository*, and my Cargo.toml is as follows:
[package]
name = "gputest"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
wgpu = "0.19"
bytemuck = "1.15"
env_logger = "0.10"
flume = "0.11"
pollster = "0.3"

However, in any run configuration (dev or release), the program panics with:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: RequestDeviceError { inner: Core(DeviceLost) }

Originating from this call:
    let (device, queue) = adapter
        .request_device(
            &wgpu::DeviceDescriptor {
                label: None,
                required_features: wgpu::Features::empty(),
                required_limits: wgpu::Limits::downlevel_defaults(),
            },
            None,
        )
        .await
        .unwrap();

The actual error value (from err.to_string) is: "Connection to device was lost during initialization"
For completeness, here is the adapter info:
 { name: "Intel(R) Iris(R) Xe Graphics", vendor: 32902, device: 39497, device_type: IntegratedGpu, driver: "Intel Corporation", driver_info: "Intel driver", backend: Vulkan }

Changing the required_features to default, empty, and all had no impact, and changing the required_limits to default, downlevel_defaults, and downlevel_webgl2_defaults were just as useless. The internet has been pretty dry on this kind of error, how can I address it and have the program run smoothly?
*Curiously, line 112 from this example seems to be an error, as rustc maintains that "struct wgpu::ComputePipelineDescriptor<'_> has no field named compilation_options" so I have commented it out.

Note that the example you linked is for the latest development version of wgpu, which is clearly different from the version you're actually using (compilation_options was added very recently and isn't part of any release yet).
